# Download app with hidden link PHP & response header

Tags: php, hyperlink, hidden

I need users to download an application from their browser. But do not know the download url.
I've implemented this:

```
<?php
$path = 'itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://www.url.com/ios/Install.plist;'
$mm_type="application/octet-stream"; 
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header('Location:' .$path); 
?>
```

The problem is that from a browser in developer mode you can see the response header with the source location.

How can I make this not happen?
Thanks

Comment: use `[Headers part]; echo file_get_contents('itms-services://?action...')`.

Comment: Hellow Justinas
can you be more concrete? Thanks